# Swift Regex & Delimiters

Tags: arrays, regex, swift, delimiter

I am parsing some HTML and parsing substrings. I have started by placing all parsed text from the elements into an array. Now I need to make functions that return an array of the substrings I need.

Here is some data I need to parse (these are the most extreme cases of what the data I am working with will look like).

let arr = [

"**ABC** **111-1** LOC (**31245**)", "**TuTh** **12:15PM** - **1:30PM** **Something 101**",
       "**MATT** **1456-1** LOC (**1248**)", "**Sa** **4:15PM** - **7:15PM** **SomePlace 532**",
       "**AC** **G7700** LOC (**1248**)", "**DATE: TBA** "

]

Each substring that is bolded is what I care about.

Im creating a loop

```
 for i in 0...arr.count - 1 {
     if i % 2 == 0 {
         let product = parseProduct[arr[i]]
         let delivery = parseSchedule[arr[i+1]]
     }
 }
```

I need help creating the parseProduct and parseSchedule functions that return an array of the parse substrings.

Final output of product array

After first loop iteration, I would like this result

```
product = ["ABC", "111-1", "31245"]

delivery = ["TuTh", "12:15PM", "1:30PM", "Something", "101]
```

Comment: Can you please give me final output array you want from an array arr.?

Comment: @karthick I just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try those regexes

- `.*?(?= LOC)` matches from start of the string to `LOC` [see here](https://regex101.com/r/LtiQ5K/1)
- `(?<=\().*?(?=\))` matches from a parenthesis to another, it will match the number in parenthesis [see here](https://regex101.com/r/LtiQ5K/2)
- `.*(?= -)` matches from the start of the string to `-`, it will match `TuTh 12:15PM` and similar [see here](https://regex101.com/r/LtiQ5K/3)
- `(?<=- ).*` matches the time `12:00PM`, from `-` to the end of string [see here](https://regex101.com/r/LtiQ5K/4)
- `DATE:.*` matches `DATE:` and everything after [see here](https://regex101.com/r/LtiQ5K/5). If you want to support lowercase `date:` too, use case insensitive `i` flag.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Swift and could not test with its regex engine so I used prep engine. Your engine might not support lookahead/behind and most of these regexes won't work.

If these aren't what you searching, leave a comment and please add more information to your question: longer array, exceptions, is it case sensitive, what pattern each bolded substring follow, etc.